# Cognitive Dissonance and Punishment: Discovery vs. Stipulated Scenario

Tags: cognitive-dissonance

According to the [Aronson & Carlsmith study, 1963](https://web.mit.edu/curhan/www/docs/Articles/15341_Readings/Motivation/Aronson_Carlsmith_1963_The_effect_of_the_severity_of_threat.pdf):

- children facing a mild punishment for playing with the toy bridge the dissonance gap by derogating it
- their attitude persists after punishment lifted, that is, don't play with the toy, contrary to severe punishment (baseline) group

What if the children in each group were not told of the punishment, but discovered it through their own attempts of playing with the toy: is there a study on this?